# JavaScript Drag & Drop with <p> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two separate `<p>` elements and what I want to do is have it so they can be clicked on, dragged, and dropped in a new location. And when they are dropped I want them to send their css `left:` and `top:` values to the console.

They start off with `top: 0`,`left: 0`. I want their final reported top and left values to be relative to their initial position. So if I drag and drop one 5 pixels to the right and 15 pixels down from their *original* position I want it to return `top: 15, left: 5`.

I'm also using jQuery if that would make this any easier to pull off. So how do I go about doing this?

Also, ideally I want them not to be accidentally selected with the text cursor when dragging and dropping. Is there a way to make them act like divs or maybe cover them with a div that fits to their shape and is above them but invisible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at jquery ui droppable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: This is great, super simple _and_ clean.